# Call Function on when app opens

Tags: html, blackberry, blackberry-10

I'm really new at BB10, but I need to update a HTML app for BB10 where I need to call a function when the app opens. I have no idea where to begin and I can't find anything on Google. Can anyone give me some direction?

EDIT: I found a file called app.js with a function `App.init = function(){..}`

Safe to assume this is where I call the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I guess I was a noob, but I just put it in the `<script>` tag where I declare the js file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/BlackBerry-Test.js">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            updateFeed(true);
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use IIFE(Immediately  Invoke Function Expression)

```
(function(){
    App.init();
})()
```